# How to resolve this error? xcode generated Project-Swift.h error

Tags: swift

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC12palaceCookie18OrangeExchangeUtil")
@interface OrangeExchangeUtil : NSObject <SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest * _Nonnull)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse * _Nonnull)response;
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue * _Nonnull)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> * _Nonnull)transactions;
@end}
```

> palaceCookie-Swift.h:353:43: Unknown class name
>   'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'; did you mean 'SKPaymentTransaction'?
>
> palaceCookie-Swift.h:353:73: Unknown class name
>   'SKProductsRequestDelegate'; did you mean 'SKProductsRequest'?
>
> palaceCookie-Swift.h:353:43: Type argument 'SKPaymentTransaction' must
>   be a pointer (requires a '*')
>
> palaceCookie-Swift.h:353:73: Type argument 'SKProductsRequest' must be
>   a pointer (requires a '*')
>
> palaceCookie-Swift.h:353:33: Type arguments cannot be applied to
>   non-parameterized class 'NSObject'

**Screenshot**

[image: Error Screenshot]

**Code:**

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class OrangeExchangeUtil: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
```

How to solve this error？Using Xcode 11.2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with mixed compilation
oc,swift,c++ 
add

```
@protocol SKPaymentTransactionObserver;
@protocol SKProductsRequestDelegate;
```

in c++ .h file